# Connection and storage

Tags: java, mysql, database, connection, web-hosting

I want to make a website done in Java language. This is for my own learning purpose. Since I am doing things myself I tend to get confused. 
If there is a Login Form wherein a huge number of people all around the world need to feed their login details and that data gets stored. 
To achieve this, do we need to have a database hosting?
Can you please guide the exact steps for this?
I know Core Java and MySql Database Basic knowledge but I have not done both app connection procedure.

I only know to code in Java and SQL queries. I had done an earlier basic application that runs only on a system (This was done in VB.NET and MySQL).I did this a decade back. Now that I am back to programming after a decade, I am bit confused about how to make this connection in a way that the Login form stores the details from the website to the database. The database should be MySql or some data hosting site? I will be trying this out on Windows System in Eclipse Neon. Let me know if you need further details.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you are well versed with Java and MySQL, you can learn about Apache Tomcat and Struts 2. 
With these, you can make an application that serves your purpose. 
At the front-end, you'll have jsps with the login form. 
With struts, you can map actions (like button clicks) to java classes. In these Java classes, in the backend, you'll have the code to connect to DB and store data.
Hope this guides you make your web application. :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It just refreshed my knowledge. So, you mean to say, I should now download Apache Tomcat App. Whether Struts 2 is a feature in Apache Tomcat or a separate app? I just did little research after your reply. I read Java servlet is faster than JSP. In Apache, there is a choice whether to go with Java servlet or JSP? Overall Eclipse will not be useful for my purpose?

Comment: Ani, with Apache Tomcat, you can have js/jsp -- front-end files in any format. 
Struts is a framework; its not a part of tomcat. 
You can think of it as a link between your js/jsps and java classes.
For example, in your login page, on clicking the "submit" button, if you set the action as "/newuser", then in struts.xml, you'll map "/newuser" to say a java class LoginAction.java and a method "addUser" . You can also specify params so that you can access them in the java class and from there, add them to DB. 
You may follow tutorial about struts-2 on tutorialspoint . It is good.

Comment: Thank you again for the brief explanation. I will try to do better research and study.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a database hosting but you need a database server configured properly at your system for localhost development.There are many sites guiding you to make a full java app using jdbc and jsp step by step you can get there easily.They will guide you to configure your database server.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Alright, I will check out those tutorials.